# For what values of x is $|x(1-x)| < 1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

> The series is:
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n(1-x)^n}{n}$$

I used the ratio test to try and find the range of values of $x$ for which a series converges, and am stuck with

$$|x(1-x)| < 1.$$

The obvious values are $0$ and $1$.

What about the rest?

I tried:

$-1<x(1-x)<1 = -1<x-x^2<1,$ which isn't helpful.

Or $|x(1-x)| < 1$ if and only if $x^2(1-x)^2<1$, which just gives me a tricky quadratic polynomial to work with, so I feel I'm no better off.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm very surprised you got $|x(1-x)|<1$ when performing the ratio test??

Comment: I set it to be less than 1 to force convergence, @charlestoncrabb ... the n's converged to a factor of 1 so I am just left with this factor...

Comment: Perhaps you should include your series, because when using the ratio test you always get a linear function of $x$ inside the absolute value (provided the limit wrt $n$ is finite)

Comment: Ok just did @charlestoncrabb :-)

Comment: I see, I apologize, I assumed it was a standard power series you were after.

Comment: No worries at all @charlestoncrabb.  Something like this has shown up on my dept's exams over the last couple years so I want to drill down a bit on these questions.  The ending is always a tricky absolute value inequality to grapple with ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
-1\lt x-x^2\lt1\\
\therefore x^2-x-1&\lt0\text{ or}&&x^2-x+1&&&>0\\
\therefore \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}&\lt0\text{ or}&&\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}&&&\gt0\\
\therefore \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2&\lt\frac{5}{4}\text{ or}&&\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2&&&\gt-\frac{3}{4}\\
\therefore -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\lt x-\frac{1}{2}\lt\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\text{ or}&&-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\lt x-\frac{1}{2}\lt\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
\end{align}$$
If $x$ is restricted to reals then we have:$$\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\lt x\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: Hi @mufasa, if I had missed the part on completing the square, which I am likely to do, could I, using your second line, set it equal to zero, use quadratic formula, split the polynomial into linear factors and then resume looking at the inequality?  I will try this now but just wondering if it's essentially the same idea as yours ...

Comment: I find completing the square much easier than using the quadractic formula but yes, it will lead you to the same result.

Comment: Thanks so much @Mufasa, I agree with you now, after some thought.  Completing the square is definitely the way to go.  Have a great day :-)

Comment: Hi @Mufasa, sorry, can I squeeze in one final question if you don't mind?  For x restricted to the reals, once you got to the case $(x - \frac{1}{2})^2 > - \frac{3}{4}$, would you immediately reject this case, since there is a need to take (positive) square roots?  And this is analogous to having a negative discriminant in the quadratic formula.  So, we only look at the other case to finalize our range of x.  Is this correct?  Thanks so much,

Comment: Yes - your reasoning is correct

Comment: Ok awesome - thanks so much @Mufasa!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Draw the polynomial $y=x-x^2$, then draw the absolute value of it (this will simply flip the negative parts across the $x-$axis), then draw the line $y=1$. The values of $x$ where the former graph is below the line will be your answer.

Comment: "Draw the polynomial"?

Comment: @FlybyNight The inside of the absolute value the OP is trying to bound is the quadratic (polynomial) $x-x^2$. You should be able to draw a parabola if you are in a calculus class?

Comment: Hi @flybynight I added the series in my question if you would like to comment on it - thanks so much,

Comment: @User001, because we want the values of $|x-x^2|$ that are less than $1$.

Comment: Hi @charlestoncrabb, this is for analysis / advanced calculus, so I am seeking a way to show it rigorously... thanks,

Comment: Often times in analysis we can prove something much more easily if we know what the answer is. If you draw the picture and get the correct values, a rigorous proof should not be far off.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb My point what that you do not "draw a polynomial". You draw the **graph of** a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with finding the values where it is equal to 1.
$$|x(1-x)|=1$$

splitting cases:

$$
\begin{array}{rl|rl}
x-x^2&=-1 & x-x^2&=1\\
x^2-x-1&=0 & x^2-x+1&=0 \\
x_{1,2} &= \frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+1} & x_{3,4} &= \frac{1}{2}\pm
\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-1}\\
x_{1,2} &\in\mathbb{R}& x_{3,4}&\in\mathbb{C}\\
\end{array}
$$

$x_{1,2}$ are of further interest. The polynomial is a parabola that is open to the bottom. It is shaped like a mountain, not a valley. If you go to either $\pm\infty$ the value will go towards $-\infty$. Hence the values outside the interval<sup>1</sup> $(x_{1},x_2)$  cannot have an absolute value smaller than 1.

---

<sup>1</sup> I think some use this notation $]x_{1},x_2[$ to denote that the interval of valid does not contain the boundaries $x_1$ and $x_2$ ,

Comment: Thanks so much @null - my geometric intuition is relatively weak, so I'd much rather do something that Mufasa does (please see above).  Although I definitely hope to gain better intuition in the near future... :-)